# Add css with if not child class condition

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi please see the following two html codes:

```
<div class="price">
  2
</div>
```

And:

```
<div class="price">
 <div class="symbol">£</div> 2
</div>
```

So in the first one I want to add `£` to the price so I am using this CSS

```
  .price::before {
     content: "£";
  }
```

And it is working . But I don't want this if `.symbol` class is already present in `.price` class. Is there is any way to do this in CSS?

Comment: Why can't you add `.price > .symbol {display: none;}`? This way you always showing the symbod via css only

Comment: Can i use Jquery?

Comment: @Alon Eitan: Could be because the symbol isn't always £, and they just want £ to be the default when otherwise not specified. But if prices are always in £, then your solution is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are applying `£` symbol as default and `.symbol` for the different symbols as @BoltClock mentioned in the comments

You can use `pseudo` classes with `position:absolute` combination...

You have to apply `position:absolute` to both `pseudo` element and `symbol` class at the same position. If there is no `symbol` class, the pseudo element `:before` will be visible and if `symbol` class is there, it will be visible above pseudo element `:before`

Here the tricky part is the setting `background-color:white` of the `.symbol` class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.price::before {
  content: "£";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.price {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="price">2</div>
<br>
<div class="price">
  <div class="symbol">$</div> 4
</div>
```

Comment: i don't  understand the answer fully , but i think it will be good one . If you can make a example in jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/ , it is better .

Comment: @abilasher you have to apply `position:absolute` to both `pseudo element` and `symbol` class at the same position. If `.symbol` is there it will be on top of pseudo element `:before` [**Fiddle Link**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/4xxLapym/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in pure CSS:

```
.price::before {
     content: "£";
} 

/* Do not show the symbol if contained into a price element */
.price > .symbol {
  display:none;
}
```

#### Why

So, CSS selectors work in a way for which a selector can only query an element's parents or siblings. It is not possible to create a selector which act by querying the children of an element. You have to reverse the order. That is why, you work on the `.symbol` class and show it or hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this class via jquery it is good aproch.

```
if( $('.price').hasClass('symbol') ) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Only that this question is not tagged under jQuery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669738/responsive-grid-box-with-image-automatically-resize

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this using `CSS` only. You need a bit of jquery here.

What my jQuery code is doing is it is adding class `.symbol-present` to `.price` which has `.symbol` element and my CSS code is then adding symbol accordingly.

```js
$(".price").addClass(function(){
  return $(this).find(".symbol-present").length > 0 ? "symbol":"";
})
```

```css
.price:not(.symbol-present)::before {
  content: "£";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">
  2
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="symbol">£</div> 2
</div>
```